# Как выполнять функцию через атрибут тега (любое событие), если она внутри $(function () {})?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Такая конструкция будет работать:

```
<script>
  function work() {
    alert("Work!");
  }
</script>
<button onclick="work()"></button>
```

Как сделать, чтобы заработала такая?

```
<script>
$(function () {
  function work() {
    alert("Work!");
  }
});
</script>
<button onclick="work()"></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const my = window.my = {}
$(function () {
  my.click = function () {
    alert("Work!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="my.click()"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант адын:

```js
var work;

$(function () {
  work = function() {
    alert("Work!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="work()">work</button>
```

Вариант два (вдруг не знали):

```js
$(function () {
  $('.work').on('click', function(){
    alert("Work!");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="work">work</button>
```

P.s. обычно скрипт размещают после HTML... страница загружается сверху вниз, и пока скрипт не будет выполнен - HTML, записанный после него, не загрузится. А если в скрипте будет запрашиваться еще незагруженный элемент - получится ошибка)